# What is the most recommended solution for cloning form rows?

Tags: jquery

[image: Example mockup of what I am intending to achieve]

I'm trying to achieve functionality illustrated in the image.

These are some of the questions I have and would appreciate your opinion:

- Should I have a a row of inputs in a div and then clone it?
- Should the names of the form elements be a matching array (name="firselement[]")?
- If Select is not selected, does it get passed as empty or skipped? I need to maintain rows as a record in DB and do not want to have missing inputs mess up the array order

Any tips in achieving this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Should I have a a row of inputs in a div and then clone it?"*

Well that would work. I would probably make each item (row) either a li element within a ul, or a tr in a table. I'd use a delegated event handler to manage the "Remove" processing, and any other event management for the fields.

> *"Should the names of the form elements be a matching array (name="firselement[]")?"*

Repeated fields don't have to have the square brackets `[]` in their name to work. I believe that putting `[]` is a PHP thing, but not all server-side languages do that (if your server-side is Java, for example, repeated request parameter names can be accessed as an array without the `[]` in the name). The browser doesn't care one way or the other.

> *"If Select is not selected, does it get passed as empty or skipped? I need to maintain rows as a record in DB and do not want to have missing inputs mess up the array order"*

If you're talking about a drop-down select element then include a default/empty option first in the list - its value (can be an empty string) will get included in the request. The text actually displayed to the user for the first option could be an empty string, or something like "--select a value--" or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

`<select>` will always pass values. If none are selected, it will pick the default one. The first one that is, that might in some cases have the value `''`.

Use `name="field[]"` as mentioned. Then the HTML of every field can simply be cloned and your system will identify them as an array, with the keys of the input and the selects having relevant keys for each row.

Basicly in your system validate is select-name got a value for each array key. You can base the array keys on the sent text input's array, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have done complete solution bins for above query. you can check demo link as below:

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp99

**HTML:**

```
<div id="panel">
  <form id="frm1">
    <div id="table1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input">
          <input type="text" size="18" name="frmtext[]"/>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
          <select name="selop1[]">
            <option value="0">
              --select--
            </option>
            <option value="1">
              option1
            </option>
            <option value="2">
              option2
            </option>
            <option value="3">
              option3
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
          <select name="firselement[]">
            <option value="0">
              --select--
            </option>
            <option value="firselement1">
              firselement1
            </option>
            <option value="firselement2">
              firselement2
            </option>
            <option value="firselement3">
              firselement3
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete">
            Delete
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="action">
        <a  href="javascript:void(0);" id="addrow">
          Add Row
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#table1{
  background:#22559d;
  width:500px;
  padding:10px;
}
.row{
  width:450px;
  padding:5px;
  margin-top:2px;
  border:1px solid #dcada9;
}
.input{
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
input, select{
  border:1px solid #adada9;
}
#table1 a{
  color:#fdddda;
  text-decoration:none;
}
#table1 a:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
  $(function() {
    $("#addrow").click(function() {
        $('.row:last').clone().insertAfter(".row:last");
        $('.row:last').find("a.delete").live('click', delRow);

        //Bind Delete Link Shows on Newly Added Row
        $("a.delete").live('click', delRow);

        /*--Here You can remove following scripts If you dont want to keep selected drop down option as on previous row ---  */
        $('.row:last').find("select:eq(0)").val($('.row:last').prev(".row").find("select:eq(0)").val());

        $('.row:last').find("select:eq(1)").val($('.row:last').prev(".row").find("select:eq(1)").val());
        /* --End of script for Selecting Drop down values --*/

    });

});

function delRow() {
    $(this).parents(".row").remove();
    if ($(".row").length <= 0) {
        $(".action").hide();
    }
}
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp99